# Why Apache(centos 7) can't see route that I made?

Tags: laravel, apache, routes, centos

I made route, but apache server cant see that route. There no problem with Laravel welcome page but when I try to make another folder in view. Apache cant see that page. 404 not found pop up.

Here is the Route and the Controller codes

```
Route::get('/pages', 'Pages@index');
```

and controller

```
    function index(){
    return "test";
```

Also my httpd my document root: /var/www/html/laravel/public

module dir:
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

Do I need to change something else too? to make this route accessible?

Comment: check mod rewrite, apache host config - allowoverride ...

Comment: try `example.com/index.php/pages` if it works then you have to enable apache mod rewrite

Comment: actually i am trying to find in mod rewite in  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf But there is no. Do i need to write it myself? if it's then how?

Comment: just check for `AllowOverride` in your host config and set it to `All` for now .. you need to allow the .htaccess file to use mod_rewrite basically ... and restart

Comment: have you tried clearing the cache? What output do you get when you run `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: if you are getting an Apache 404 page, not a Laravel 404, means mod_rewrite is't working .. you can find 100s of answers to help with that if you search

Comment: Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action                           | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+----------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure                          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure                          | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | pages    |      | App\Http\Controllers\Pages@index | web          |

Comment: also I tried to this <Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory> and also this <Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory> But no change I can access with like this example.com/index.php/pages but not like .com/pages

Comment: Sorry Mates, I changed the wrong overall, Now it's working thanks for the helps!

Comment: good luck with your project and enjoy using Laravel :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in centos 7, `None` --to-> `All` makes it fine.

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
. . .
 # 
 # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
 # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
 # Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
 #
 AllowOverride None --> All  
. . .
</Directory>
```